# Добавить TextView в программно созданный LinearLayout

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

Вот код:

```
LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
linearLayout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
linearLayout.setPadding(dpToPx(left), dpToPx(top), dpToPx(right), dpToPx(bottom));
linearLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(dbHelper.KEY_MAINCOLOR))));

TextView newTextView = new TextView(this);
newTextView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
newTextView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
newTextView.setText("123456");

linearLayout.addView(newTextView);

toAddGroups.addView(linearLayout);
```

Но он почему-то он работает не правильно: Создается два `linearLayout`, но пустые, без `TextView`. Что я делаю не так?

Причем, если я добавляю такой `textView` в `toAddGroups`, то он добавляется.

Comment: может лейаут параметры `TextView` надо указывать как `ViewGroup`?

Comment: когда добавляете linearLayout, обязательно указывать ориентацию linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL); А вообще, я думаю, у Вас что-то с цветами, попробуйте поменять цвета фона и текста, к примеру, Layout-у присвоить Color.WHITE, а textView Color.BLACK. Если ничего не изменится, закомментируйте padding для layout, возможно, в них проблема. А так должно все работать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Добавить `TextView` в программно созданный `LinearLayout`

Пусть корневым контейнером у нас будет `FrameLayout`, то есть:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/root_frame_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Создаем `LinearLayout` и задаем ему атрибуты:

```
LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
linearLayout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
```

Создаем и конфигурируем `TextView`:

```
TextView textView = new TextView(this);
textView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
textView.setText("New TextView");
```

Добавляем созданный `TextView` в `LinearLayout`, а затем `LinearLayout` в корневой `FrameLayout`:

```
linearLayout.addView(textView);
mRootFrameLayout.addView(linearLayout);
```

---

Касательно Вашего примера: я чуть-чуть изменил код (вручную задал отступы и цвета):

```
mRootFrameLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.root_frame_layout);

LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
linearLayout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
linearLayout.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
linearLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#00FF00"));

TextView newTextView = new TextView(this);
newTextView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
newTextView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
newTextView.setText("123456");

linearLayout.addView(newTextView);
mRootFrameLayout.addView(linearLayout);
```

И этот код работает корректно. Проверьте, какой цвет Вы устанавливаете для `linearLayout`, не `#ffffff` случайно? В таком случае надпись будет сливаться с фоном.

Comment: Ага, спасибо) Подставил ваш код - заработало, проблема была в паддингах) Моя функция dpToPx была неверно сделана

Comment: post_zeew, возможно, вам лучше воспользоваться готовым решением при конвертировании  dp  в px https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4605527/converting-pixels-to-dp

Comment: @VolhaGomel, Мне?

Comment: извиняюсь, не Вам, а Mr Klonwar